# Run time error type 13 type mismatch when copying formula result that is an Error

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The macro opens-copies-closes from an external file back to the master file. Issue arises from copying from ONE particular file.

Attached is the code and ** to indicate where the error occurs.

```
Sub UpdateDate_Click()

Dim readLastCell As Long
Dim readLastCellNameSheet As Long
Dim billNumber
Dim SheetName As String
Dim billNumberNamesheet As Long
Dim ExecutiveWorkBookPath As String
Dim excelFilePath
Dim ExecutiveWorkBook As Workbook
Dim MainTemplate As String

MainTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Name

'ChDir Defaulth path
excelFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
Application.EnableEvents = False
strFilename = Dir(excelFilePath & "\*xlsm")

Do While strFilename <> ""
  'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  If InStr(strFilename, "Executive") > 0 Then
    Set ExecutiveWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath & strFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
    ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Unprotect "12345+"
    ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:Q220000").Locked = False

    readLastCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    readLastCellNameSheet = ExecutiveWorkBook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 4 To readLastCell
      cell = "A" & x
      billNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

      If Len(billNumber) = 0 Then Exit For

      For N = 4 To readLastCellNameSheet
        cell = "A" & N

        '**
        billNumberNamesheet = ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value

        If Len(billNumberNamesheet) = 0 Then Exit For

        If billNumberNamesheet = billNumber Then
          cell = "R" & N & ":" & "AX" & N
          copycell = "R" & x & ":" & "AX" & x
          ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Copy
          ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range(copycell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll    
        End If

      Next N

    Next x
```

My code is supposed to copy an entire line (one out of 20 columns has formula) into another workbook. So the error popped up because there was a formula that equates to an error (#N/A),(#Error)?

I need to copy regardless if the formula equates to an error. The formatting in the master workbook will correct that error.

Comment: `ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value` is probably an error in the cell like `#N/A` or some other error.

Comment: @scott craner sorry, super novice here. So how do I solve the error? with the .value means if it's a formula the error will pop up. So the ideal situation is to make sure the code caters to both formula and value?

Comment: @Carmen `.Value` works just fine with formulas, but it will not work if the formula evaluates to an error. You could try `If Not IsError(Cell.Value) Then DoSomething`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney, understood. So if I want the same code to work even though it's with error, how do I input it in the code? If Not IsError(Cell.Value) Then ___________?

Comment: @Carmen You don't want the code to use the value of the cell if it has an error. That's why I wrote it that way. Working with an error value in the cell will likely lead to an error...

Comment: @BrandonBarney with my initial code, it is supposed to copy an entire line (one out of 20 columns has formula) into another workbook. So the error popped up because there was a formula that equates to an error (#N/A),(#Error)? I just needed it to copy regardless if it equates to an error or not cause the formatting in the master workbook will correct that error. Is there a code that could overwrite that?

Comment: If you step through the code using F8, what line does the error occur on ?